# Connection string for azure table storage for local connection

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am new to cloud development with the combination of azure table storage + node.js. In all samples I found the connection string for azure storage is only those who have account with real windows azure. As I am developing in my local PC need to the configuration of local azure storage account.

I tried with connection string as:

```
<add key="AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT" value="DevStorage"/>
  <add key="AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY" value="Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="/>
```

It is possible connect azure storage via azure storage emulator not in code.

Can anyone get me the solution please??

Answer (score 1):

Create your node.js table service client like this:

```
var azure = require('azure');
var tableClient = azure.createTableService(ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT, ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY, ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_TABLE_HOST);
```

By using DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT, DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY and DEVSTORE_BLOB_HOST, you're using the blob storage emulator settings which are [hard coded](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/serviceclient.js#L55) in the node.js Azure SDK.  This eliminates node.js configuration problems from the equation.

Comment: Hi Jmac, Thanks for your response. Am using azure table storage not blob one. I need to know the value of DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT, DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY and DEVSTORE_TABLE_HOST which runs in local PC (local azure emulator) not in real cloud. I used the key values as <add key="AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT" value="DevStorage"/>
  <add key="AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY" value="Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="/>
but it's not working for me shows some connection error. i hope you could do me some help in this issues.

Comment: I edited my code snippet to use the table storage client.  You can see an Azure SDK example here: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/examples/tasklist/server.js#L15  Like I said before, using the DEVSTORE_* constants will allow you to bypass any configuration problems when working with the storage emulator.  Once you get your code working locally, you can fiddle with the AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT and AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY configuration settings to point to a live Azure Storage account.

Comment: Just for anyone who bumps in here, this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/395) is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try the connection information below to see if it's help.

Account Name = devstoreaccount1

Account key = Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==

Comment: Hi Xu,Thanks for the response.Got the error as:iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.HRESULT:0x2 HTTP status:500 HTTP reason: Internal Server Error You are receiving this HTTP200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.The last 64k of the output generated by the node.exe process to stdout and stderr is shown below: C:\node\tasklist\WebRole1\server.js:20   throw error;
              ^

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with nodeJS, might not be able to help you. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I has storage emulator running on outside virtual machine using Passport to redirect external requests at ports 20000, 20001, 20002, to localhost port 10000, 10001, 10002 inside this virtual machine...

```
var connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://192.168.56.56:20000/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://192.168.56.56:20002/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://192.168.56.56:20001/devstoreaccount1;';

var azure = require('azure-storage');
var tableSvc = azure.createTableService(connectionString);

var query = new azure.TableQuery()
  .top(5)
  .where('PartitionKey eq ?', 'CONDITION');

tableSvc.queryEntities('TABLENAME',query, null, function(error, result, response) {
    if(!error) {
      // query was successful
      console.log(result.entries);
    }
  });
```